# Regex that finds a specific word that doesn't match a specific upper/lowercase?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to have a regular expression that matches a specific word that doesn't match the specific upper/lowercase?

For example: FooBar - I'd like to look for this word only if it doesn't have a capital F and B and the rest lowercase.

```
foobar - match
FooBar - not match
aWord  - not match
fOoBaR - match
```

Comment: Why does `fOoBaR ` match even though it has a capital `B`?

Comment: Because both f and b have to be capital, and the rest need to be lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option which would also match `Foobar` which I understand would be a correct match, since only one letter `F` is capital and not both (`B` and `F`), correct?

```
(?!FooBar)([fF][oO]{2}[bB][aA][rR])
```

| Word | Match |
| --- | --- |
| foobar | yes |
| FooBar | no |
| Foobar | yes |
| aWord | no |
| fOoBaR | yes |

Answer (score 1):

##### This regex:

```
^f[oO]{2}[bB][Aa][rR]
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ssd7g/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `f` | f |
| `[oO]{2}` | any character of: 'o', 'O' (2 times) |
| `[bB]` | any character of: 'b', 'B' |
| `[Aa]` | any character of: 'A', 'a' |
| `[rR]` | any character of: 'r', 'R' |

Comment: This regex isn't matching `FooBAr` but should be because the `a` is capital